# VBA basic script for reading xml data?? Resource for learning this method?

Tags: xml, vba, vbscript, excel, xsd

So I was just looking for basic examples of reading xml structure data with visual basic subs/scripts.

specifically, if possible, how can i take structure data of xml, read the data with some vba, and lay it into excel spreadsheets?

or just a learning resource for this type of thing. thanks very much!

Comment: There are two basic ways you might approach this given what you explained: 1) Use VBA from **within Excel** to read an XML doc and populate a spreadsheet or 2) Use VB.NET and COM interop from **outside Excel** to create an Excel document.  The latter would probably be easier. Which method do you want to use?

Comment: @Ben, to be honest which ever makes more sense to use is fine, but I would like to learn both actually...

Comment: The more overlooked option is to use ADODB to create a spreadsheet (for those situations when you don't have Excel installed).  This is a handy secret to know when you are running scripts on PC's that may not have Excel installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These three topics will help you get started.

1) Load the XML using [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28VS.85%29.aspx) hint - XMLDOC.Load ("D:\folder\yourXML.xml")

2) Read the data with [XPath](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/examples.html) or XML navigator

3) Build Excel Spreadsheet Using [Microsoft Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/06/16/reading-xml-files-in-vba/

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/01/21/culling-you-rss-feeds/

These aren't tutorials, just a couple of examples of XML in Excel that might help you identify the objects properties and methods.  The first one from 2009 was my first attempt (read: it's terrible) but the comments were helpful for me so they might be helpful for you too.

Comment: @dkus I'm impressed that you even *attempted* to read XML from within VBA. Very well done and thanks for the link!