# how to extract variable name and its values from xml file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have following xml file & I would like to extract variable name & its value. can you please help me out to get this done.
My xml format is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyApps.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyApps.Properties.Settings.dbConnString" connectionString="Data Source=MSTEST01\TQA;Initial Catalog=TQA;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserID;Password=Pwd"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <MyApps.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="BasePath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>\\Results</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="cPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Controller</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ePath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Debug\E.exe</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="fPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Framework</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="engineId" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="wPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\S5</value>
            </setting>
        </MyApps.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

and I am expecting the output like e.g. executablePath="D:\MyExe.exe"

Thanks in advance

Comment: the first 2 points of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2181953/69820) should get you started

Comment: @Nathan Rice I tried below code and able to get the required value and variables but stuck to  retreive connectionstring variable and its value Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\test\myxml.xml")
strQuery = "/configuration/applicationSettings/MyApps.Properties.Settings/*"
Set colItem = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strQuery)

For Each objItem In colItem
 If objItem.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
   MsgBox objItem.Attributes(0).Text & ": " & objItem.Text
 
 End If
Next

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following as well. Leverages getAttribute - Cscript vbs.

```
Set objXML2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML2.async = "false"
strdir="c:\config.xml"
If (Not objXML2.load(strdir)) Then
    wscript.echo "Unable to load file '" & strdir & "'. "
    WScript.Quit(1)
End If

Set colNodes = objXML2.selectNodes ("/configuration/applicationSettings/Eunner.Properties.Settings")
For Each objNode in colNodes
    wscript.echo objnode.getAttribute("name")& " : " & objNode.text
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my answer, can someone suggest better option if any? below is script that wrok for me

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\STEPRunRequest\STEPRunner.exe.config")
strQuery = "/configuration/applicationSettings/Eunner.Properties.Settings/*"

Set colItem = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strQuery)
Set xmlElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/configSections[@connectionStrings]") '='" <SomeValue> & "'
Set queryNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(".//node()[@connectionString]")
MsgBox queryNode.Attributes(1).Text

For Each objItem In colItem
 If objItem.Attributes.Length > 0 Then
   MsgBox objItem.Attributes(0).Text & ": " & objItem.Text

 End If
Next
```